# Нужны ли запятые после слов "впервые" и "тренировки"?

Tags: запятые

Впервые за все три их тренировки в её глазах блеснула толика переживания за собственную шкуру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Впервые за все три их тренировки в её глазах блеснула толика переживания за собственную шкуру.*

Никаких запятых здесь больше не нужно - это не оборот, не уточнение, обычное обстоятельство.